# Posting something that happened to Facebook through an HTML Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I've looked through several tutorials on using the Facebook API, but none of them address what I'm trying to do.

I'm working on a website for a small college. When the user applies online, they would like it to redirect to a page with a link that will put a post on your Facebook wall that says, "Billy just applied to Awesome State College" with a link to apply and an image of some sort (probably the school's logo).

I guess it would be similar to the way Facebook games throw up posts, saying "Gertrude just clubbed 300 baby seals in 'Clubbing Baby Animals Pro'!" But I wouldn't need to create a whole new Facebook app for this, would I?

Answer (score 0):

Posting on a user's wall requires an access token, which you can get with the help of
one of Facebook SDKs, which will need your app id.

Reference for posting on user's wall:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
See section Publishing.

You can use Facebook Javascript SDk as the need is simple:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/